# There is no $n$ such that the digits of $16^n$ form a decreasing sequence.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Show that there is no $n$ such that the digits of $16^n$ in base $10$ form a (non necessarily strictly) decreasing sequence. For example $64$ or $9331$ are decreasing sequences.

You can bash this mod $10^k$ for some big (but fixed) $k$ but as this was an exam problem I would like to see a more computation free approach.

Comment: Try mod 100, then see what you can do with $...76$

Comment: But 76 is exactly the problem, If you want to deal with it you habe to look to (10^5)^n but more cases appear

Comment: For the brute force approach, $\bmod 10^7$ is enough.

Comment: @MishaLavrov You can post your answer, which I think is the intended one.

Comment: @WhatsUp I don't know what's intended by the exam problem, but the question specifically asks for *not that answer*.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Alright... I would be surprised if there is an answer requiring less amount of calculation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was a computer available for this exam?  So far, I've come up with nothing better than the $10^7$ argument and that's really not available with pencil and paper, and not so easy with a standard calculator.

Comment: @lulu Can you check if your solution is identical to mine? Mine doesn't require much calculation (def no computer needed), though it also goes out to $10^7$.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Definitely different than mine!  All I did was to check every case $\pmod {10^7}$.  Well, I asked my computer to check them for me, I should say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observation 1: The last digit of $16^n$ is always 6.

Observation 2: The last 2 digits of $16^n$ is divisible by 4, so have to be 76 or 96 in order for the string to be decreasing.

Observation 3: $n \geq 7$ by checking the first few cases. (In fact, we just need to check $n = 3, 5 $ due to observation 2.)

Observation 4: $16^n > 10^n$, so we can talk about the last $n$ digits without worrying about an initial string of 0's. (This is helpful with the subtraction later.) This last $n$ digits must be a multiple of $2^n$.

Observation 5: If $16^n \equiv 96 \pmod{100}$, then for a decreasing string we must have $ 16^n \equiv 10^n - 4 \pmod{10^n}$, which is not a multiple of $8$. So $ n\leq 2$, which we have ruled out.

We now focus on $16^n \equiv 76 \pmod{100}$. For a decreasing string, it looks like     $\underbrace{9\ldots9}_{x} \underbrace{8\ldots8}_{y} \underbrace{7\ldots7}_{z} 6$.
Then $ 16^n \equiv 10^n - \underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a} \underbrace{2\ldots2}_{b}4 \pmod{10^n}$.
Set $R = \underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a} \underbrace{2\ldots2}_{b}4$, which is a multiple of $2^n$. (Note that $ a + b \leq n-1$, though we will not use it.)

Observation 6: For $\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a} \underbrace{2\ldots2}_{b}4$ to be a multiple of 4, it must be $\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a} \underbrace{2\ldots2}_{b-1}24$.

Observation 7: For $\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a} \underbrace{2\ldots2}_{b-1}24$ to be a multiple of 8, since 24 is divisible by 8, the prior digit must be 2, so it must be $\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a} \underbrace{2\ldots2}_{b-2}224$.

Observation 8: For $\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a} \underbrace{2\ldots2}_{b-1}24$ to be a multiple of 16, since 224 is divisible by 16, the prior digit must be 2, so it must be $\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a-1}\underbrace{2\ldots2}_{b-3}2224$.

Observation 9: For $\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a-1}\underbrace{2\ldots2}_{b-3}2224$ to be a multiple of 32, since 2224 is NOT divisible by 32, the prior digit must be 1, so it must be $\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{a-1}12224$.

Observation 10: $112224$ is not a multiple of 64. So $n \leq 6$.

---

Notes

- As you'd have realized, the leading string of 1, 2 is initially not restrictive. If we had a choice of even and odd, then we can always continue the string.
- However, once we're forced to choose 1 (odd), then our only remaining choices are 1 (odd), and it cannot always be continued. That's the motivation for Observation 6-10.

Comment: I don't get why do you consider only two case. Possible remainders of $16^k/100$ are $16, 56, 96, 36, 76$

Comment: @Raffaele Because the string is decreasing.

Comment: I think this answer is simply the comment of @MishaLavrov, and somehow the OP doesn't like it. Also you seem to have made it unnecessarily complicated. Just start with $6$ and keep adding larger digits to the front and test divisibility of powers of $2$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Hm. My interpretation was " a lot of computation is needed" even to the extent of "a computer has to be used". I feel that my solution doesn't need that, the division is almost obvious.

Comment: Agree about "start with 6 and keep adding larger digits", though it was easier for me to work with 1 and 2 (IE Use 1 if the dividend was odd, use 2 otherwise), instead of 7, 8, 9. Ultimately it's the same.

Comment: Ah, I just realized that the OP might mean testing all numbers up to $10^7$. That of course is only doable with a computer.